# Project fleld by value in another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

***Record*** collection contains an array of.

```
Field1: 'some values'
Field2: 'some values'
```

***Project*** collection contains project condition

```
Field1: 1
Field2: 0
```

The above scenario needs a query that only shows Field1.
because project collection says to show only Field1

I came up to this.

```js
db.Record.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'Project',
      localField: '',
      foreignField: '',
      as: 'Project',
      pipeline:[]
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$Project',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      Field1: {"$Project.Field1":{$eq:1}},
      Field2: {"$Project.Field2":{$eq:1}},
    },
  },
]);
```

this will show like an array of {Field1:1, Field2:2} It can recognize. the value is present. I just want the value to be resolved.

Record Collection will have multiple records but Project collection will only have one collection.

Comment: Why are `localField` and `foreignField` empty in your `$lookup`? You should fill those parameters in with the field names from the two collections that you want to match on

Comment: @user20042973 because we don't need any because I use pipeline value. hear just copy the value from the Project collection to every record in aggregate.

Comment: You're sure that you want _every_ document in `Project` collection applied to every document from `Record`? In either case, you need to simplify the definitions inside of `$project`. It should be something like `Field1: "$Project.Field1"`. [Here is a playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GEpNbeaaKUG)

Comment: @user20042973 i don't want to show data from project collection with simple join. I want to use data from Project collection as a criterion for whether to show data in Record collection or not.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking to [Conditionally Exclude Fields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#conditionally-exclude-fields).

In general, if field `x` is the optional field to include, and field `y` is the one indicating whether or not it should be included, then the portion of the `$project` definition to do so will use the `$cond` operator and look similar to the following:

```
"x": {
  $cond: {
    if: "$y",
    then: "x",
    else: "$$REMOVE"
  }
}
```

In your particular case, `x` is represented by `Field1` and `y` is represented by `Project.Field1` (and similarly for `2`). So your `$project` stage should look similar to the following:

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      Field1: {
        $cond: {
          if: "$Project.Field1",
          then: "$Field1",
          else: "$$REMOVE"
        }
      },
      Field2: {
        $cond: {
          if: "$Project.Field2",
          then: "$Field2",
          else: "$$REMOVE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

A working [playground example is here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DbqXeUhe8N6).

There were two general things wrong with this approach that you originally tried:

```
Field1: {"$Project.Field1":{$eq:1}}
```

The first is that [the `$eq` operator in aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) has a different structure. It takes the form `{ $eq: [ <expression1>, <expression2> ] }`.

The second, and bigger, problem is that apart from true/false values, [the other input you can provide when expressing field names in projection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-project) are expressions via `<field>: <expression>`. This syntax "*Adds a new field or resets the value of an existing field.*" Using `$eq` alone would resolve to just `true` or `false`, which would then be set as the value of the field.

Helpfully, the rest of the description for that syntax is what points us to the approach using `$cond` outlined above: "*If the the expression evaluates to `$$REMOVE`, the field is excluded in the output. For details, see
[Exclude Fields Conditionally](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#std-label-remove-var).*"